# Java sout to console and file

Tags: java

Is it somehow possible to print both to file and console?

If I make

```
PrintStream fileStream = new PrintStream(logPath);
System.setOut(fileStream);
```

it will only print all System.out.println() to file, but I also need to see it in console.

Comment: why not make your own logger class, that performs both,

Comment: I am with @Stultuske here - the use of `System.out` / `System.err` in production code is discouraged anyway. Just take a look at SLF4J - and don't use log4j. The latter will give you severe headache.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is.You just need to write your file using Buffer writers and use S.O.P at the end of the function or according to the things you want to print to your console.

Comment: I think you are getting negative comments for the dismissive answer. Giving some details (e.g. a possible implementation, with the full class name) would help you to get more upvotes.